# Refer the XSD located in a jar using schemaLocation?

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, xsd

I am using Spring and Maven. I have **ProjectA** and **ProjectB**. **ProjectA** is a dependency to **ProjectB**. Am trying to refer an XSD in **projectB**'s WSDL  but the XSD is part of **ProjectA**.

How can i refer the XSD which is part of dependent jar?

When i did as below:

```
schemaLocation="classpath:/src/main/resources/xsd/some.xsd"
```

I got an exception saying `unknown protocol classpath`.

Please help me to refer the XSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSDL is transferred as is and interpreted by the client. So `classpath:` isn't going to work as, it already says, isn't a valid protocol. You will have to put a URL in there which is upon requesting translated to the URL you want. You could use Spring Resouce mapping for that (i.e. externally put `http://.../xsd/some.xsd` which is mapped with Spring MVC `<mvc:resources mapping="/xsd/**"  location="classpath*:/xsd" />`.

You shouldn't include `src/main/resources` as everything in `src/main/resources` is put into the root of the class path.

Comment: Deinum, thnx for ur answer. as the XSD is part of the dependent jar, how can i deal with it?

Comment: As stated in the answer… You can retrieve it with the resource handling.

Comment: Deinum, what is http://.../xsd ? how can i give this url ? Is it complete path to my xsd?

Comment: Yes. You can,probably, leave out the `http://.../` and only do the path on your server (`/yourapp/xsd/some.xsd`).

Comment: Thanks Deinum.. do i need make any entry into web.xml?